# What must I do to make edits on a DataGridView immediately available?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a list of `FileItem` objects, via a `FileItemBindingSource`. I want to simply bind the grid to my list, and let the user check or uncheck a checkbox column for each item, and then on a button click, get all checked items from the grid. Right now, if I use the following code, even with some boxes checked in the UI, the objects returned all have Checked set to false.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    FileItemBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Dim allFiles = DirectCast(FileItemBindingSource.DataSource, IEnumerable(Of FileItem))

    Dim checkedFiles = allFiles.Where(Function(f) f.Checked).Select(Function(f) f.FilePath)

End Sub
```

I bind the data as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    FileItemBindingSource.DataSource = GetFiles()

End Sub
```

What must I do to get the edits on my Checked column?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put Datagridview.beginInvoke(); before you pull the checked objects.

I had this issue too. Last checked row was never included or last unchecked row was always included. Howerver, I don't have access to that code and I'm not 100% sure this was the command to use.

Comment: It's worth noting that I achieved what I wanted by doing away with the BindingSource and binding my objects straight to the grid. That isn't a real answer though.